# What is the equivalence of the command "set /p" present in bash, in efi shell?

Tags: shell, uefi

I need the command that asks the user to write some input and then store it in a variable.

In the terminal I was using the command like this:

```
set /P SP=Enter the product model: 
set /P SS=Enter the serial number: 

\SCRIPT\******.exe /SU AUTO /SP %SP% /SS %SS%
```

But I can't find a similar way to do it with EFI shell commands, there is a `set` command, but I can't use it in the same way.

I tried with the `-v` option, but I didn't get the result I expected.

Update : Thanks for your answers.

Yes i think that set /p is a cmd command.

The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input entered by the user. Displays the specified promptString before reading the line of input. The promptString can be empty.

the example I took with the SP and SS allows me to ask the input user for a value for example the product name with SP and the serial number with SS, and then I run a script that will allow me to change the SMBIOS values ​​and make it transparent to the user who only needs to enter the values.

Comment: There is no `set /p` in Bash. I guess you are actually talking about the legacy Windows command shell `cmd`.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/questions/666474/where-can-i-find-out-input-command-from-efi-shell seems to ask the same question, but only got a completely useless answer (basically "google it")

Comment: Since there is no such bash command, you would have to specify what this `set /P` exactly is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native "input" command in EFI Shell, so, in order to deal with this problem, you can try some different approaches:

1. Create an .efi application, you can use ReadKeyStroke function to get the user input
2. Create a python script, you will need to have python binary in the same device that EFI shell file is. You can build python following the steps available on edk2 lic repo (https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-libc/tree/master/AppPkg/Applications/Python/Python-3.6.8)
3. Use .txt file previously filled by the user and explore the command "parse" to get the information and set it as shell variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look at which solution is the most appropriate for my case.